# Bootstrap Nav Walker - Hover Drop down stopped working suddenly

Tags: php, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4, wp-nav-walker

My nav was working just fine, when I tried it this morning, the parent nav that has children won't drop down on hover like it did before and also the parent nav links stopped working? Weird. I checked my code in the class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php and everything is the same?

```
 if ( isset( $args->has_children ) && $args->has_children && 0 === $depth && $args->depth > 1 ) {
    $atts['href'] = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '';
    $atts['data-toggle']   = 'dropdown';
    $atts['aria-haspopup'] = 'true';
    $atts['aria-expanded'] = 'false';
    $atts['class']         = 'dropdown-toggle nav-link';
    $atts['id']            = 'menu-item-dropdown-' . $item->ID;
} else {
    $atts['href'] = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '#';
```

JS:

```
  $('.navbar .dropdown').hover(function() {
      $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true,true).delay(250).slideDown();

      }, function() {
      $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(100).slideUp();

      });

      $('.navbar .dropdown > a').click(function(){
      location.href = this.href;
      });`
```

[image]

I have no clue what happened, or what I can do to fix where you hover over items that have children, it should fire the dropdown. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing more of your code. Is the dropdown purely CSS or does it use javascript? If it uses JS then check your console log to see if there are JS errors - once an error occurs in js, it can prevent any more JS from running.

Comment: No errors is js log. It is using js for its drop functions. Edited original post

Comment: Recently all CDN from Bootstrap got updated to the 5.0 alpha, It caused major issue for all site using Bootstrap CDN as Bootstrap dropped JQuery in the 5.0. Your error might be coming from that... Like @FluffyKitten said without any code nor link to your website we can't do much more.

Comment: Geez. Okay. Like I said I hadn't touched it and it stopped working. Its a normal nav walker setup. Ill look and see if I can roll back somehow. Thank you.